# SQL update statement from select

Tags: sql-server

I would like to update a column in a table using another column coming from a `select` statement. This what I'm trying:

```
UPDATE CostFile
SET UPrice = (
SELECT

        (
            dbo.EmployeeDailyTrans.DailyCost
        ) + (
            dbo.EmployeeDailyTrans.OverTimeHoursCost
        )
     / 
        (
            dbo.EmployeeDailyTrans.NumberOfHours
        ) + (
            dbo.EmployeeDailyTrans.NumberOfOverTimeHours
        )

FROM
    dbo.EmployeeDailyTrans
WHERE
    dbo.EmployeeDailyTrans.EmployeeCode = 'UNE25681'
)WHERE  Code = 'UNE25681'
```

but I got this error:

> [Err] 21000 - [SQL Server]Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
>   01000 - [SQL Server]The statement has been terminated.

Comment: Your select query is returning more than one row, so the error...

Comment: This seems seems pretty self explanatory, might add a `TOP 1` to the inner select as it would appear `EmployeeCode ` is not unique perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to speculate, I'm guessing you want aggregation:

```
UPDATE CostFile
    SET UPrice = (SELECT (SUM(edt.DailyCost + edt.OverTimeHoursCost) /
                          SUM(edt.NumberOfHours + edt.NumberOfOverTimeHours)
                         )
                  FROM dbo.EmployeeDailyTrans edt
                  WHERE edt.EmployeeCode = CostFile.Code
                 )
    WHERE Code = 'UNE25681';
```

Answer (score 0):

Your update is set up to update records with a single value.  Your query returns more than one result.  You need to refine your select to return just one row.  Since many trans records are available for that employee code you can use Top or a window function to get a anticancer record or perform an aggregation.  If you post a little more detail as to what you are trying to achieve you could get some help with the syntax.